# Pass Jenkins build parameters to pipeline nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I created a new Jenkins pipeline. The pipeline is (currently) parametrized with a single boolean option named `VAR_A`. My pipeline script is:

```
node ('windows') {
    echo "$VAR_A"
    bat 'env'
}
```

When I manually build the project with `VAR_A` checked, "true" is echoed, as expected. The list of environment variables, however, does not show `VAR_A=true`.

I am able to get `env` to show `VAR_A` if I wrap the call in a `withEnv` block:

```
node ('windows') {
    echo "$VAR_A"
    withEnv(["VAR_A=$VAR_A"]) {
        bat 'env'
    }
}
```

I will more parameters than this, so specifying each parameter individually is not desired. **Is there a way to transfer all build parameters to a node's environment?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The point is that in Pipeline scripts the job parameters are not injected into the environment automatically as for regular jobs. Each parameter becomes a variable of the Pipeline script [binding](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html). Therefore you can access them directly by name.

In your example `echo "$VAR_A"` variable substitution is performed by groovy in the context of your script (see [Groovy doc on strings interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_string_interpolation)). That's why you don't see it in the `bat` output.

For each parameter you want to inject you need to add a line like this:
`env.VAR_A = VAR_A` in the beginning of your script. It can be outside of `node` block because `env` is global within the whole script.

Alternatively there is a way to add all the script vars, including parameters and even Pipeline built-in vars i.e. `steps` into the environment. Unfortunately it will require some whitelisting to run in a sandbox:

```
@NonCPS
def populateEnv(){ binding.variables.each{k,v -> env."$k" = "$v"} }
populateEnv()
```

Example:
*VAR_A* is a parameter.
Script body:

```
def AAAA = 1 // such a definition doesn't put variable in the binding
BBBB = 2     // creates a binding variable. Absolutely the same behavior as for a job parameter.

@NonCPS
def populateEnv(){ binding.variables.each{k,v -> env."$k" = "$v"} }
populateEnv() // at this point injection happens

CCCC = 3      // created after the injection hence it won't appear in env.
node ('windows') {
    bat 'env'
}
```

In the `bat` output you will find `VAR_A` and `BBBB`.

IMO unless your job has tens of parameters defined `env.VAR_A = VAR_A` approach is preferred as more simple, straightforward, and requiring no approvals.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the node dynamically in the build job step is a good feature. It helps to run multiple jobs parallelly on different nodes. The addition of the following script in the Jenkins pipeline script might be helpful.

```html
def build_one() 
{
        parallel  one: { 
            stage('XYZ') {
                        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult:'FAILURE') {
                        
 build job: 'yourDownStreamJob', parameters: [[$class: 'NodeParameterValue', name: 'NodeToRun',labels: ['nodeName'], nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility']], string(name: 'ParentBuildName', value: "XX"), string(name: 'Browser', value: 'chrome'), string(name: 'Environment', value: 'envName')]
                        }
            }
        },
        two : { 
            stage('SecondArea') {
                        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                         build job: 'yourDownStreamJob', parameters: [[$class: 'NodeParameterValue', name: 'NodeToRun',labels: ['Your'], nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility']], string(name: 'ParentBuildName', value: "XYX"), string(name: 'Browser', value: 'firefox'), string(name: 'Environment', value: 'envName')]
                        }
            }
        }
        
} 


build_one()
```