# Jenkins Pipeline Plugin pass build Job parameters between jobs started in a pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Would be grateful for a decent full code example of how to pass parameters (parameterized build) from `JobA` to `JobB` in Jenkins Pipeline plugin?

I am using a script like below and can not figure from the docs how to access parameters from `JobA` in say a build step shell script in `JobB`:

```
build job: 'JobA', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'CVS_TAG', value: 'test']]

build job: 'JobB', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'CVS_TAG', value: 'test']]

echo env.CVS_TAG
```

Above gives an error:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CVS_TAG for class: groovy.lang.Binding

And can not access `$CVS_TAG` in a build step shell script in `JobB`.

Thanks

Per you responses I have also tried this unsuccessfully:

build job: 'JobA', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'test_param', value: 'working']]

env.test_param=test_param

echo ${test_param}

The error is always:

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: test_param for class: groovy.lang.Binding at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)

Comment: This answer might give you a clue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079913/pass-jenkins-build-parameters-to-pipeline-nodes/37090331#37090331

Comment: Did you enable "This project is parameterized" in Build JobB? Also note that you can access the Parameters in this way ${CVS_TAG}.

Comment: Have a look into the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675194/how-to-obtain-the-folder-where-the-pipeline-jenkinsfile-is-checked-out-jenkins

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am not able to get this working? Any working script examples using build job?

Comment: Any ideas what I am doing wrong? This seems like the most important feature when using a pipeline and there is very little in the way of doc's / example of how to use it?

Answer (score 3):

Upstream JobA:

```
//do something
env.CVS_TAG = 'test'
build job: 'JobB'
```

Downstream JobB:

```
import hudson.EnvVars
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl
import hudson.model.Cause

def upstreamEnv = new EnvVars()
node {
    //if the current build is running by another we begin to getting variables
    def upstreamCause = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(Cause$UpstreamCause)
    if (upstreamCause) {
        def upstreamJobName = upstreamCause.properties.upstreamProject
        def upstreamBuild = Jenkins.instance
                                .getItemByFullName(upstreamJobName)
                                .getLastBuild()
        upstreamEnv = upstreamBuild.getAction(EnvActionImpl).getEnvironment()
    }
    def CVS_TAG = upstreamEnv.CVS_TAG
    echo CVS_TAG
}
```