# How to obtain the folder where the Pipeline Jenkinsfile is checked out (Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, jenkins-pipeline

We're having a big project (in terms of size), that we're trying to build using a `Jenkinsfile` that is checked inside the project itself.

In order to conserve disk space and build times we try to minimize the number of copies, so what we would want is to use the folder where the `Jenkinsfile` is checked out, since that is already a repo fully cloned.

Manually investigating, I've seen that there is a `workspace@script` folder created inside the job's folder. That is folder path that I would like to obtain.

I would have expected `pwd()` to do the trick, but for some reason that works only inside nodes, resolving the path to that folder.

```
stage "Build"

def scriptWorkspace=??

node {
  sh """
    TERM=xterm ls --color /etc
    set

    docker run ... -v ${scriptWorkspace}:/mercurial-repository ...
  """
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pending an implementation of [JENKINS-33273](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33273) for the SCM you are using (Mercurial in this case I suppose? would require use of the “caching” feature in that plugin), `Jenkinsfile` is always checked out on a private workspace on the master node, not available to the script itself.

Comment: I ended up hardcoding the path in the Jekinsfile. I will change to the scm checkout, and mount the sources as a volume at some point.