# How to set Jenkins Build parameter in a job and pass to next pipeline stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We are using a Jenkins build pipeline which calls a number of Jenkins jobs.  I'm trying to figure out how to set a variable as part of a Jenkins job (each run can in theory set this variable to something unique). First problem is I'm not sure how to set such a variable as part of the first job. Second is I'm not sure how to extract that variable from the job on the pipeline via the Groovy script.

Example is:

```
node {
   stage 'First Job'
   //I want to set a parameter as part of the build steps in this job
   build 'first-job'
   stage 'Second Job'
   //I want the variable set in the first job passed in here
   build job: 'second-job', parameters: [string(name: 'FOO', value: myParam)
}
```

Comment: You can get parameters from "First job", not pass to "Second job". Look at my example http://stackoverflow.com/a/38101073

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that easily because it is not really the pipeline philosophy.

Using old freestyle projects, you would have chained your jobs such as :

```
Main job -> First job -> Second job
```

...passing build parameters from upstream job to downstream job each time.

However with [pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/#why-pipeline) the philosphy is quite different and aims to do treat all your complex workflow as a single pipeline. To keep it clean you could load functions, and it becomes very very simple to pass and get variables.

Example :

```
node {
   def functions = load 'functions.groovy'

   stage 'First part'
   def outputParamOfPart1 = functions.function1(yourParameter)

   stage 'Second part'
   def outputParamOfPart2 = functions.function2(outputParamOfPart1)
}
```

And so on. I think you should really rethink the way you are treating your different jobs. If you absolutely need to keep your jobs as separated jobs and not as some pipeline's functions, you can always have a look at Jenkins global properties.