# Pipeline Groovy code to call parameterized build w/interger parm failing

Tags: rest, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Please go easy on me, I'm relatively new to Jenkins, and very new to Pipeline/Groovy.  We're running Jenkins v2.7.1 in a lab, with all the latest requisite Pipeline plugins.

My goal is to create a basic demo of a two- or three-step Pipeline build.  It will get triggered by a Git push (got that working).  I have two granular traditional Jenkins build jobs that work fine separately in Jenkins.  I'd like to wire them together, but have found that I have to learn yet-another new language, Groovy, to get that to work.  Ugh.  After hours and hours of reading and web searching, I just can't seem to find the answer to my problem.  For simplicity's sake, I want to define an integer variable in a script, and pass it to a Jenkins build step.  I can't seem to get the right syntax to pass an integer to the build step.  Here's the error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface java.util.List is named IntegerParameterValue
```

At this point, I'm not trying to pass parameters between stages.  Just trying to get that second stage (a parameterized build) to accept an integer parameter.

```
node {
    stage name: 'prep-build-env', concurrency: 1
    echo 'Prepping build environment...'
    build job: 'php-env-prep'
    echo 'Done prepping build environment.'

    stage name: 'sample-rest-call', concurrency: 1
    def sleepduration = 10
    echo 'Executing sample REST call...'
    build job: 'Sample-REST-call-to-automation-service', parameters: [$class: 'IntegerParameterValue', name: 'sleepduration', value: sleepduration]
    echo 'REST call completed.'
}
```

This issue is similar to this:
[Pass Jenkins build parameters to pipeline nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079913/pass-jenkins-build-parameters-to-pipeline-nodes/37090331#37090331)

I'm trying to take baby steps with Pipeline/Groovy at this point.  I have the 'Sample-REST-call-to-automation-service' build job successfully calling out to a REST service using a curl command.  I'll eventually need to figure out how to build a JSON request body...  But that's "walking," I'm not even "crawling" yet!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Try wrapping the parameter in another pair of square brackets to make it a Groovy list (with only one element):

```
build job: 'Sample-REST-call-to-automation-service', parameters: [[$class: 'IntegerParameterValue', name: 'sleepduration', value: sleepduration]]
```